# How can I make a 'PD' battery port pass 9v instead of standard 5v?

Tags: batteries, controller

I wanted to get a standard lightweight phone charger to power my DIY portable device. I have tested it with 9v which works but I'm realizing that for those 'PD' chargers I'll need something on my device to signal to the battery the request for the 9 volts.

How can I make the charger pass me 9v from its 'PD' port?

Cheers!

Comment: You just asked this an hour ago!  You need the same sort of IC for which that shopping request was closed.  Follow the path of inquiry already recommended at the question you seem to have deleted...

Comment: As I commented in your deleted question, I expect that most  "standard lightweight phone chargers" will only provide 5 volts.  Check the specs on the charger you plan to use before doing much work on this.

Comment: You need to include a USB-PD client controller. Either integrate one into your board or buy a product that does it for you. Tons of options on Google.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Hey that message was marked to delete by a admin here don't blame me for following what I was asked to do! I deleted it and created a new question (this instead).  It doesn't matter whether I mention asking for suggestion how to get something as well does it? It needs to be procured either way. The main parts of both my old question and this was about *what* electronic piece was needed. Perfectly valid question it would seem to me.

Comment: Thank you very much @user1850479 that perfectly answers my question! :)

Comment: Hi @user18...  when I type in "usb pd client controller" into the search fields of big online electronics retailers nothing at all is returned. Is there another name for them?

Comment: Cool, I'm finding some now that suits my purpose!

Comment: I thought accusing people of abusing the site was part of the ubfriendly/unkind rule. Did that change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name for these add on modules to enable USB Power Delivery or Quick Charge voltages are called trigger modules. "Trigger" is the keyword.

If you want to design your own then you can use an usb power negotiation IC like TIs TPS25741A or NXPs PTN5100 or any number. Googling "usb power ic" should show a ton. Make sure you include what type of protocol you need like PD or QC and maybe version. They are not intercompatible but many changers may support both. My usb power bank supports QC 2.0 but not 3.0, and not PD.

Comment: Thank you very much! 'Trigger' seems to ehhh trigger some good search results! :)  From my trials I think that 'Decoy' might be another word used for those?
Yeah I definitely want to just purchase one and not build it myself. I'm more of a cobble-together kinda guy! :)